# How to reverse bar chart if store has mixed data with positive and negative values?

Tags: extjs

I  have to display a bar chart which has mixed data in the store with negative and positive values to be shown on y-axis. I want to display the chart like in this image: https://assets.highcharts.com/images/demo-thumbnails/highcharts/column-negative-default.png

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name','someField'],
            data: [{
                "name": "A",
                "someField": -21414
            }, {
                "name": "B",
                "someField": 22034
            }, {
                "name": "C",
                "someField": -16270
            }, {
                "name": "D",
                "someField": 20838
            }, {
                "name": "X",
                "someField": 2720
            }]
})

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {

            items: [{
                xtype: 'cartesian',
                width: '100%',
                height: 500,
                store: store,
                insetPadding: 40,
                innerPadding: {
                    left: 40,
                    right: 40
                },
                axes: [{
                    type: 'numeric',
                    fields: 'someField',
                    position: 'left'
                }, {
                    type: 'string',
                    fields: 'name',
                    position: 'bottom',
                }],
                series: [{
                    type: 'bar',
                    xField: 'name',
                    yField: 'someField',

                }]
            }]
        });
```

The origin should be at 0.
I tried using postion:'radial' in place of 'bottom', but, using this removes the x-axis and also the labels are not seen.
 How can I reverse the y-axis values so that they can be flipped below x-axis(upside down)?

Comment: you can use thresholdLineRange plugin to achieve this. check this out.. https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?250596-Threshold-Lines-and-KPI-Ranges-for-Cartesian-Charts

Comment: Is there any other way without using this plugin?